# MergeSort on LinkedList

Tags: java, mergesort

I have homework - write a Merge Sort algorithm in java. I used LinkedList to store my data. I try to converting pseudocode from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) to java, but it doesn't work. I don't know why and I need your help guys.

It's my MergeSort Class.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MergeSort {
private final Comparator comparator;

public MergeSort(Comparator comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
}

public LinkedList sort(LinkedList list) {
    if(list.size() <= 1) {
        return list;
    }

    LinkedList left = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList right = new LinkedList();

    int middle = list.size() / 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
        left.add(list.get(i));
    }

    for(int i = list.size(); i >= middle; i--) {
        right.add(list.get(i));
    }

    left = sort(left);
    right = sort(right);

    return merge(left, right);
}

public LinkedList merge(LinkedList left, LinkedList right) {
    LinkedList result = new LinkedList();

    while(left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0) {
        if(left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0) {
            if(comparator.compare(left.get(0), right.get(0)) <= 0) {
                result.add(left.delete(0));
            }
            else {
                result.add(right.delete(0));
            }
        }
        else if(left.size() > 0) {
            result.add(left.delete(0));
        }
        else if(right.size() > 0) {
            result.add(right.delete(0));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

In it is a "StackOverflowError Exception". I try to remove bug, but I can't. Thanks for your  help.

P.S Sorry for my terrible language. :(

Comment: I don't immediately see anything that causes a stack overflow, but it's worth pointing out that for a LinkedList, getting the size and getting the i-th element are both "slow" operations (linear in the length of the list).  So your sort algorithm, as written, will end up being very slow (even if you fix whatever is causing the stack overflow).  How big is the list that you're trying to sort?

Comment: Definitely do not implement mergesort with linkedlists

Comment: Mergesort with arrays runs in 2n space, but your mergesort with linkedlists runs in n^2 space, which is a bad thing; might as well use insertionsort or selectionsort instead if you don't want to use arrays/arraylists

Comment: It is not good to use raw types because of unchecked casts. Use `LinkedList<?>` for better style. (or if you do not support `Comparator`, use `LinkedList<? extends Comparable>`.

Comment: @durron597 You can use `toArray()` to convert the list into an array, sort the array, then clear the passed-in list, then call `addAll(Arrays.asList(sortedArray))` on the list.

Comment: If you're working with the build-in linked list, you should avoid `size()` and `get()`. Pretty much everything you need can be done by getting an `Iterator`. A list is empty if `list.iterator().hasNext()` returns `false`. And if it's not, you can get the first element out of it with `iterator.remove()` - use this to split the lists.

Comment: @gparyani At which point you might as well quicksort the array. (Or better yet, timsort, which is both stable and performs well on arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

On line 33 your upper array index needs to start at list size minus one:

```
        for(int i = list.size()-1; i >= middle; i--) {
```